# Stream.into + Stream.run identical to Enum.into?

Tags: elixir

Elixir allows you to use `Stream`s instead of `Enum`s to prevent intermediary copies of collections. But when you're on the last step, would it even matter?

Even when you get to the smallest details isn't this

```
Stream.concat(header, rows)
|> CSV.encode
|> Stream.into(output)
|> Stream.run
```

the same as this?

```
Stream.concat(header, rows)
|> CSV.encode
|> Enum.into(output)
```

If so, why would [the `Stream.into/3` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#into/3) advocate the pairing of `Stream.into` + `Stream.run` and not just say `Enum.into`?

Perhaps it's a simple as just being more readable and discoverable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your two examples don't really do the same thing. The first one just runs the stream pipeline, while the second one will also give you a return value. Since  you are not using the result, `Stream.run` is just fine in this case.

Generally, if you're interested in the result of a stream you can always use the `Enum` counterparts in the last step of a pipeline. `Stream.run` will *not* return the results, but rather apply the pipeline and then return `:ok`. This is useful if you're interested in the side effects rather than the actual return value.

I suppose the reason we have `Stream.into` as well is that it might *not* actually be the last step in the pipeline. Here's a contrived example:

```
output = IO.stream(:stdio, :line)

Stream.iterate(0, &(&1 + 1))
|> Stream.chunk(2, 1)
|> Stream.into(output, &"BEFORE: #{inspect &1}\n")
|> Stream.map(fn [x, y] -> x * y end)
|> Stream.into(output, &"AFTER: #{inspect &1}\n")
|> Stream.take(3)
|> Stream.run
```

Which will output

```
BEFORE: [0, 1]
AFTER: 0
BEFORE: [1, 2]
AFTER: 2
BEFORE: [2, 3]
AFTER: 6
```